# How to print figure to clipboard by PRINT function with the quality identical to 'Edit-->Copy Figure' option?

Tags: matlab, figure

Is there any way to print the figure to the clipboard so that the quality is identical to what the `Edit-->Copy Figure` option provides?

I used to save the figure to powerpoint file by using saveppt.m obtained from [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/340). It worked well until yesterday. I noticed that the stored image quality was somehow degraded. I tried to re-generate some ppt slides with exactly the same script and the same source data, but the new slides are simply of worse quality.

I investigated into this problem a little bit and discovered that when the figure is copied to clipboard by running `print -dmeta`, the image in the clipboard is already degraded, while if I use the `Edit-->Copy Figure` option in the figure window, I get the image as clear as the original image in the figure window.

Following is an example for your reference. I copied the image from a figure to the clipboard by two different methods, and paste it to Microsoft Paint program, and cut a piece of it to show below:

The image using `print -dmeta`: [image: stored figure using "print -dmeta"]

The image using `Edit-->Copy Figure`: [image: stored figure using "Copy Figure"]

If you compare the Xtick label '50', you may see that the image from `Edit-->Copy Figure` is smoother.

At the beginning I thought it was a problem of the resolution, but setting `-rN` to change the resolution does not seem to resolve my problem, at least not for N<=300.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself. Using `print -dmeta -painters` to specify the renderer resolves my problem.

In `File-->Preference-->Figure Copy Template-->Copy Option` I noticed there are 3 options:

1. Metafile
2. Preserve information
3. Bitmap

I found that if I select 1, the `Edit-->Copy Figure` outputs the same image as `print -dmeta`. So I kind of confirmed the information I need is in the `Preserve information` option. A quick google search led me to the discussion about the potential difference of the applied renderer, and eventually I confirmed that using `painters` will print the image to the clipboard in the way I wanted.

The image in the question seems to be generated by the renderer `zbuffer` and `painters`, respectively. I still don't know why the default renderer of `paint -dmeta` changes, though.

Answer (score 6):

**The short answer...** Use the same function invoked in the callback for that menu item:

```
editmenufcn(gcf,'EditCopyFigure');
```

**The longer answer...** How exactly did I find this? You can look at [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763175/in-matlab-how-do-you-save-a-figure-as-an-image-in-the-same-way-as-using-save-as/3763277#3763277) to a [related question about reproducing what is done by a File menu option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763175/in-matlab-how-do-you-save-a-figure-as-an-image-in-the-same-way-as-using-save-as). The concept is the same, just for a different figure menu. For example, this will find the callback you want for the currently active figure window:

```
>> hCopyFigure = findall(gcf,'Label','Copy &Figure');  %# Handle for the "Copy
                                                       %#   Figure" menu item
>> get(hCopyFigure,'Callback')  %# Callback invoked when that item is selected

ans =

editmenufcn(gcbf,'EditCopyFigure')
```

The function EDITMENUFCN is another one of those sparsely documented functions, but looking through the code (by typing `edit editmenufcn.m`) shows that it either invokes Java (if you're on a Mac) or the undocumented function UIMENUFCN.

Comment: Gah! Just when I was about to submit the post! +1 for speed. BTW: Matlab has also a `clipboard` function, which, unfortunately is just for strings.

Comment: +1 for the quick fix. However, it will be great if I can get the parameter/properties that makes the `print -dmeta` as good as the `Edit-->Copy Figure`. After all, the Copy Figure option is not under my control, and the image quality may go bad someday with no reason, just like what I encountered yesterday.  I changed the title of my question to address my need better.

Comment: Here's an article I wrote about this topic (or in general, how to use and modify the default Matlab toolbar and menubar callbacks): http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/modifying-default-toolbar-menubar-actions/