# Blurry label text in matlab plots

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm having some matlab plots. when I save the plot and then put it in my word document and then save it as pdf file. I get the plot labels blurry and some letters is unclear ?!

```
plot(d1,S,'*');
title('Frequency','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',11);
xlabel('delta','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',11), ylabel('sigma','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',11);
```

why does that happened (got angry)?!
how can I fix it ?!

Comment: As a guess, are you saving the figure as a raster format like .jpg or .png? If so, just save it as a vector format like .eps or .wmf (or just go Edit -> Copy Figure and paste it into your document, since you're using Word).

Comment: yes Im saving in jpg or bmp. how can I save it as a vector format ?

Comment: Use .eps or .wmf, or go lookup which of the other formats in the list are vector formats (I can't remember the whole list).

Comment: if you are working interactively, try `print -dmeta`. This will copy the figure into the clipboard. Next open Word, and simply paste it: Ctrl-v. Otherwise use `print` with some vector format as suggested

Comment: Consider using the widely used function [export_fig](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) from the file exchange. This makes it much easier to get publication quality figures.

Comment: Hi Amro, when I use print -dmeta, it will copy the image size exactly as it is. I want to have it larger. How to do it ?!

Comment: with `-dmeta` you cant, it captures the image at the same resolution of your monitor. Use other formats and specify the resolution: `print -dpdf -r 600`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many discussions about this on the web, but non of the solutions actually satisfied me when I wanted to export a graph to an image.
Anyway here is what I've done:

```
MyFont = {'FontName', 'Times New Roman', 'FontSize', 25};
graph_size = [1200 800]; % in pixels

fig_h = figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [10 50 graph_size]);

% Do your plot
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
plot(x, sin(x))

set(gca, MyFont{:}); % Adjust all the font sizes in the axes
```

Now you can copy a vector-based version (which is nicest quality as @wakjah mentioned) to clipboard with [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) (as @Amro said):

```
print -dmeta
```

Or with [`hgexport`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgexport.html) which exports to `metafile` again:

```
hgexport(figH,'-clipboard')
```

However you need to adjust the graph_size and `FontSize` in `MyFont` manually to get your desired output. But the good thing is that if you want it for some publication you just need to do it once.

Please note that although you are exporting the graphs as a vector-based format but your graph lines would still seem fractured if you zoom on them but they are not blurry. This is why you might want to increase the size of your graph on screen (`graph_size` and consequently the `FontSize`) to have a more accurate graph.

Hope this helps.

Related posts:

[MATLAB: print a figure to pdf as the figure shown in the MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256516/matlab-print-a-figure-to-pdf-as-the-figure-shown-in-the-matlab)

[In matlab, how do you save a figure as an image in the same way as using "Save As..." in the figure window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763175/in-matlab-how-do-you-save-a-figure-as-an-image-in-the-same-way-as-using-save-a)